# How to retrieve the current minute and check if that minute is in a file

Tags: linux, bash, date, time

I have a script that runs every minute and I want to check if the current minute is included in a variable that gets assigned from a text file.

clip_time=(< /home/project/data/clip_time.cfg)

clip_time.cfg is a text file that looks like this:
00,05,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55

in a if statement: 
If the current minute from "date '+%M'" is in the variable, say "45" then
do this, if not, do this

it would trigger if the minute is 45, but not 46, 47, 48, 49. But trigger on 50.

So in other words, run the script every minute, and if the minute is in the variable, do this, if not sleep for 30 seconds and continue.

The variable wont necessarily be every 5 minutes. It could be 05, 08, 11, 22, 35.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is by checking that the clip_time string contains the current minute as a substring:

```
clip_time="$(cat /home/project/data/clip_time.cfg)"
minute="$(date +%M)"

# The 2 asterisks make this a glob match, which should find that
# minute in the list, if it's in there
if [[ "$clip_time" == *"$minute"* ]]; then
    echo "$minute is in the list"
else
    echo "$minute is NOT in the list"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

To store the current minute in a variable do this

```
minute=$(date +"%M");
```

Then to search, you can use `grep`

```
echo $(grep $minute file.txt);
```

Here is the manual page for grep

http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of grep and date together like this:

```
grep "\b`date "+%M"`\b" test
```

with word boundaries and can even add -q flag to return a 0 or 1, like this:

```
grep -q "\b`date "+%M"`\b" test
```